# How to treat non design component initialization errors?

Tags: delphi

For start, lets take an exemplification:

You create a new VCL application project in Delphi and put a `TIBDataBase` and type in the path and name of the database file with the extension `.IB` ok?

Now, If you you just put `example.ib` and leave the path behind, when you execute your application without Delphi, it will open the database normally if the `.EXE` is in the same path as the `.IB` but if you run your application from Delphi, it will raise an error because it can't find the database file, because Delphi changes the working directory.

Sometimes you want to leave the `Active` property of that component set to `True` while you are developing, and them set to `False` and change it during the start of the application, when you deliver to your client. All that because he/she may want to install in a different path and your application has to find the proper place of the database before open it.

The problem comes when you already delivered to your client and still make some changes everyday on the code. You then have to deploy at least once a day, and sometime you just forget to set that property back to `False` and when the client receives the update and tries to run it, he/she gets a not found database error.

**The question is, how can I handle that error if this opening happens automatically when the component is loaded in memory and the activation of the database does not happens in my own code?**

Comment: The *appropriate* answer is to remember to set `Active` to false before deploying. If this isn't enough, then perhaps build events which pop up a message reminding you to disable it?

Comment: I mean, it's like asking how to make your program recognize when you made a mistake and fix it for you. Am I wrong? Advice: Don't mention anything in your question about your specific database scenario. Keep it simple and to the point, about catching exceptions from controls during form creation.

Comment: Things like `function IsDebuggerPresent: boolean; stdcall external 'kernel32.dll';` are tools for us, developers, to work with this scenario I just explained. Projects that we make or correct while the user still operates are very common. To forget to switch off some of our tools is not rare (and it's not a sin) and may come to prejudice the user when for example, he/she is getting clients orders in McDonalds. Have you consider this before you judged my question?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't be saying anything about it if you hadn't written a whole story about how you make mistakes during deploying. Like I said, just keep your question simple and to the point of the goal. It's good to use that as an example, but not the primary focus.

Comment: Sounds like you need to formalize your release process. Automate it: Write a script to change the property value and invoke the compiler. If that doesn't give you a releasable piece of software, then you're not ready to release yet. Your customers won't specifically care whether your release process is automated, but they'll notice and appreciate when you stop sending them updates that are DOA.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "general method". If your scope were the the active database flag, I could post an answer to that question.

Comment: I would appreciate that @jachguate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you are going to find a general solution to preventing run time exceptions from design time property settings without modifying the component or deriving a descendent.

For `TIBDatabase`, set the property `AllowStreamedConnected` to `False`.  This stops `TIBDataBase` from automatically connecting to the database at run time when `Connected` is `True` at design time.  `TIBQuery` using this `TIBDatabase` will not open even it is set Active at design time.

Some other database connection components have similar properties.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the database issue **only**: if I understand you correctly, my solution requires you to write an event handler for the 'BeforeConnect' event as shown below:

```
procedure TDM.SQLConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
var
 dir: string;

begin
 with TRegIniFile.create (regpath) do  // I keep my database locations in the registry
  begin                          // but you can use any method of getting the location
   dir:= ReadString ('firebird', progname, '');
   free
  end;

 with sqlconnection1 do
  begin
   close;
   params.values['database']:= dir;
   loginprompt:= false;
  end;
end;
```

This way, you can have one location stored in your database for local use, but have different locations for different users.